# How to get the same bin widths for variable bin ranges in a histogram using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, data-visualization

I am trying to create a histogram with a custom bin range. However, as you can see in the histogram below, the bin widths are not a constant size.

[image]

Ideally, I want something like this. The spacing between bins doesn't really matter, I just want each bin/column to be the same width:

[image]

The code I used to generate the first histogram is this:

```
plt.figure()
weights = np.ones_like(data)/float(len(data))
plt.hist(data, bins=[0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0, 25.0, 90.0], weights=weights)
```

Comment: Do you want the bin widths to be **graphically** the same size, or **numerically** the same size?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I want them graphically the same size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a histogram is really what you want here. Usually a histogram has a continuous x axis and in the example you showed the a axis values are categorical. In that case I would suggest binning your data and getting the bin counts first. Then plotting a bar chart. Like so:

```
data = np.random.randint(0, 90, 500)
bins = np.array([1,3,5,10,25,90])
digitized = np.digitize(data, bins)
counts = np.bincount(digitized)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(np.arange(counts.size), counts)
ax.set_xticklabels(['', '0\N{DEGREE SIGN} - 1\N{DEGREE SIGN}', '1\N{DEGREE SIGN} - 3\N{DEGREE SIGN}', '3\N{DEGREE SIGN} - 5\N{DEGREE SIGN}', '5\N{DEGREE SIGN} - 10\N{DEGREE SIGN}', '10\N{DEGREE SIGN} - 25\N{DEGREE SIGN}', '> 25\N{DEGREE SIGN}'])
fig.show()
```

[image]